# How to Load the database Table on scroll down in Mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pageload

Hi all i have table which has a bulk data and a Screen for showing this data..i want o show data to the users like this

if a user goes to this screen i have to display only the first twenty of the records of my Database and when he wants to see more and scrolls down the data should be loaded on scroll down and i should show him again the Other 20 records of my DB..so as he scroll s down the page should load with that data should be populated to the page

i have been searching about this a lot but didn't get what i wanted...or how can i do this....can any one tell me how can i do this...

Answer (score 1):

Rob Conery wrote a great [blog post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132919/jquery-paging-scroll-in-asp-net-mvc) about this

He uses JQuery to make an ajax call to his controller to load more data. Here's the method he uses to load more:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            loadMore();
        }
    });
var current=0;
function loadMore() {

    if (current > -1) {
        current++;

        $('#loading').html("<img src='/content/images/bigloader.gif' />");
        $.get("/archive/index/" + current,
        function(data) {

            if (data != '') {
                $('#results').append(data);
                $('#loading').empty();
            } else {
                current = -1;
                $('#loading').html("<h3><i>-- No more results -- </i></h3>");
            }


        });
    }
}
</script>
```